# Programming in Lua on OS X?

Tags: macos, lua

What can I use to program Lua script on Mac OS X? I'm looking for something that I can use to compile/interpret Lua script on OS X.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Lua source easily compiles with no changes on the mac. It will build lua (the interpreter which can act on a source script, a pre-compiled script or interactively) and luac which can be used to pre-compile source scripts.

From the [lua.org](http://lua.org/) website: http://luabinaries.luaforge.net/download.html. The ones you want are the darwin binaries (they say Mac OS X in the description).

Comment: I dont think i was clear, i'm looking for something that i can use to compile/interpret lua script on the mac. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Yes, you were clear, exactly: the standard Lua source does this. Just download and build it or (I'm sure) you can find lua and luac prebuilt somewhere.

Comment: Hm id rather not build something as i havent the first clue where to start, i guess ill whip out google...

Comment: Here are some step-by-step directions for building the Lua source on Mac OS X, as Jason Coco suggested: http://luanova.org/2007/11/10/launch-getting-lua-installed/

Comment: Ok, let me clarify that; i'd like a precompiled version.

Comment: I edited the answer with a link to the binaries that was found at lua.org under their downloads section.

Comment: I found that separately but they're just a bunch of files that the mac doesn't know what to do with. do i need osmething in particular to run them?

Comment: You need to untar them and put them somewhere they can be executed (like /usr/local/bin). The files you care about will be lua5.1 and luac5.1. You can rename these (or simlink these) to lua and luac respectively. Assuming this downloads to your Downloads folder, you can issue this in the terminal: cd foo; tar -xf ~/Downloads/lua5_1_4_Darwin94x86_bin.tar; sudo cp lua5.1 luac5.1 /usr/local/bin; sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/lua5.1 /usr/local/bin/lua; sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/luac5.1 /usr/local/bin/luac

Comment: replace cd foo above with cd /tmp. after that, you can run lua or luac from the command line.

Comment: @RCIX Honestly, I think it would have been faster and easier to compile and install Lua from source using the directions from the link that I posted.  Since I already had Apple's Developer Tools installed, it took me less than 5 minutes from the time I opened http://www.lua.org in Safari to the time I had lua and luac installed in /usr/local/bin.

Comment: I honestly have to agree with las3rjock :)

Comment: Looks like Xcode is too big for my hard disk (dont ask), so im going to try another route...

Comment: Just follow my directions in the early comment... cut and paste them with the ; in place or replace the ; with a new line in the terminal

Comment: i'm attempting to use macports right now. Thanks for all of your attempts to help though!

Answer (score 21):

My preferred way:

```
brew install lua
```

Thanks, Max!

And if you need to know how to install Homebrew, see [Link](https://brew.sh/) and:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
```

Answer (score 7):

My favorite way (from the shell):

```
sudo port install lua
```

I LOVE macports!

Comment: For this, of course, you'll need to install MacPorts. Fortunately, that's easy: http://www.macports.org/install.php

Comment: when i run it it does nothing, and i have xcode + macports installed.

Comment: Nothing? Did you enter your sudo password correctly?
When I installed it, it downloaded some thing, configured it, and I could then launch with the lua command. Make sure :/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin is in your path

It installs the executable in /opt/local/bin/

Answer (score 5):

Here is my terminal session from compiling and installing Lua from source, basically following [these directions](http://luanova.org/2007/11/10/launch-getting-lua-installed/).  I already had Apple's Developer Tools installed, and /usr/local/bin was already in my PATH, so I was able to skip some of the more time-consuming and/or tedious steps in the directions.

```
$ cd ~/Downloads

$ tar -xf lua-5.1.4.tar

$ cd lua-5.1.4

$ make macosx    
cd src && make macosx
make all MYCFLAGS=-DLUA_USE_LINUX MYLIBS="-lreadline"
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lapi.o lapi.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lcode.o lcode.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o ldebug.o ldebug.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o ldo.o ldo.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o ldump.o ldump.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lfunc.o lfunc.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lgc.o lgc.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o llex.o llex.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lmem.o lmem.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lobject.o lobject.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lopcodes.o lopcodes.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lparser.o lparser.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lstate.o lstate.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lstring.o lstring.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o ltable.o ltable.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o ltm.o ltm.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lundump.o lundump.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lvm.o lvm.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lzio.o lzio.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lauxlib.o lauxlib.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lbaselib.o lbaselib.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o ldblib.o ldblib.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o liolib.o liolib.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lmathlib.o lmathlib.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o loslib.o loslib.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o ltablib.o ltablib.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lstrlib.o lstrlib.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o loadlib.o loadlib.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o linit.o linit.c
ar rcu liblua.a lapi.o lcode.o ldebug.o ldo.o ldump.o lfunc.o lgc.o llex.o lmem.o lobject.o lopcodes.o lparser.o lstate.o lstring.o ltable.o ltm.o lundump.o lvm.o lzio.o lauxlib.o lbaselib.o ldblib.o liolib.o lmathlib.o loslib.o ltablib.o lstrlib.o loadlib.o linit.o
ranlib liblua.a
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o lua.o lua.c
gcc -o lua  lua.o liblua.a -lm -lreadline
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o luac.o luac.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_USE_LINUX   -c -o print.o print.c
gcc -o luac  luac.o print.o liblua.a -lm -lreadline

$ make test
src/lua test/hello.lua
Hello world, from Lua 5.1!

$ sudo make install INSTALL_TOP=/usr/local
Password:
cd src && mkdir -p /usr/local/bin /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib /usr/local/man/man1 /usr/local/share/lua/5.1 /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1
cd src && install -p -m 0755 lua luac /usr/local/bin
cd src && install -p -m 0644 lua.h luaconf.h lualib.h lauxlib.h ../etc/lua.hpp /usr/local/include
cd src && install -p -m 0644 liblua.a /usr/local/lib
cd doc && install -p -m 0644 lua.1 luac.1 /usr/local/man/man1

$ lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print "Hi"
Hi
> = 2 + 3
5
> ^c

$ cd test

$ lua factorial.lua 
0! = 1
1! = 1
2! = 2
3! = 6
4! = 24
5! = 120
6! = 720
7! = 5040
8! = 40320
9! = 362880
10! = 3628800
11! = 39916800
12! = 479001600
13! = 6227020800
14! = 87178291200
15! = 1307674368000
16! = 20922789888000
```

Comment: Thank you! that INSTALL_TOP line did it for me. Why is this needed here?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to compile your own Lua binaries, you can try [ZeroBrane Studio Lua IDE](http://studio.zerobrane.com/), which comes packaged as a .dmg file for OSX. It's an IDE that allows you to edit and debug your Lua scripts. If you are just starting with Lua, it also includes 50+ examples and demo scripts, as well as integrated instructions on running them, so you won't be facing an empty screen not knowing where to start.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently found [Rudix](http://code.google.com/p/rudix/)—a maintained collection of precompiled Unix software for Mac.

While I'm sure you've already figured out a way of installing Lua, I came across your question by Googling the same thing. For anyone that's interested, [here's the link to a recent Lua 5.1.4 dmg.](http://code.google.com/p/rudix/downloads/detail?name=lua-5.1.4-4.dmg&can=2&q=)

Comment: Regarding Rudix, You can get more info on Running Lua on Mac OS X here:

http://rudamoura.com/luaonmacosx.html